# Local docker and k8s react differently

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

I have a simple docker-image based on `nginx:alpine`. On my local docker-deamon I can start it without any problems. 
But when I deploy it via k8s, then the container fails to start with the following error:

> 2020/03/04 08:01:38 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
>   nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid"
>   failed (13: Permission denied)

Has anybody an idea what happend? I bet, that there is something wrong with the k8s-cluster.

And my dockerfile looks like this:

```
#Dockerfile
# build nginx-container
FROM nginx:alpine

# delete nginx-default-page and creates non root user
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/* \
  && addgroup --gid 98761 nonroot \
  && adduser -u 9876 -G nonroot --disabled-password nonroot \
  && touch /var/run/nginx.pid \
  && chown 9876:98761 /var/run/nginx.pid \
  && chown -R 9876:98761 /var/cache/nginx

# copy our conf and web into nginx
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY static-webfiles/* /usr/share/nginx/html/

USER 9876:98761
```

### Edit

Here is the yaml for deployment. There is no same named deployment and I assign it to k8s with `kubectl apply -f deloyment.yaml`. Iam sure that the deployment using the docker-image.

```
#deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment

metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    app: frontend
    environment: review

spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
      environment: review

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
        environment: review

    spec:
      containers:
        - name: frontend
          image: frontend:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

### Edit²

On my mini-kube-cluster the same image runs without any problem.

### Edit³

I think there is docker-layer-caching issues. All environments, that are previous using the root-image, fails on this bug.
When I build the docker-image locally and push it, then is all fine.
The only thing, that I changed in Dockerfile was the non root-updates.

I will delete all cached versions in our repos and and try it again.

Comment: How exactly do you run it on kubernetes, provide the complete manifests.

Comment: Hello, would you mind sharing some details about your setup? How are you running Docker (&k8s, respectively)? Any of them local (or in some VM / cloud provider / etc)? If local, what's your OS? In your container what's the process owning nginx?

Comment: I added my deployment. The k8s-cluster came from our company and I have not much informations about. But I think, that is no important with docker.

Comment: I tested the same image on my own minikube-cluster and there was all fine.

Comment: Can you check if both the local and k8s images are same by checking the sha

`docker images --no-trunc` and `kubectl get pods -o=yaml`

Comment: Also, can you check with pinning the base image version without being generic ie change the base image to `nginx:1.17.8-alpine`

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi with `kubectl describe pod XXX` I ensured that I have the right docker-image. I will try the non-generic version of nginx. Hold on.

Comment: Same result with `nginx:1.17.8-alpine`.

Comment: Even the sha hash is the same for the image?

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi yes.

Comment: Try with this dockerfile https://pastebin.com/5GFpT4RX

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209014/discussion-between-tummala-dhanvi-and-akop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'am pretty sure that the bug comes from kaniko.
See this https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/issues/550
and https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/issues/647

So, we can't build with our Pipelines and build images local until we update our kaniko.